# "Internet not reachable" error within VSCode Dev container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I've ran into an error when loading a project within a VSCode dev container. I get the following error :

```
 => ERROR [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 2/6] RUN if [ "true" = "  15.7s
------
 > [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 2/6] RUN if [ "true" = "true" ]; then s
u vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh && sdk install
 maven """; fi     && if [ "false" = "true" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 &&
. /usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh && sdk install gradle """; fi:
#0 15.66 ==== INTERNET NOT REACHABLE! ==========================================
=========
#0 15.66
#0 15.66  Some functionality is disabled or only partially available.
#0 15.66  If this persists, please enable the offline mode:
#0 15.66
#0 15.66    $ sdk offline
#0 15.66
#0 15.66 =======================================================================
=========
#0 15.66
#0 15.67 This command is not available while offline.
------
```

The dev container then proceeds to fail to build.

I've tried :

- reinstalling docker
- reinstalling vscode (Both to latest and an older version)
- downgrading dev container extension
- reinstalling wsl2
- recloning entire project

Any thoughts on what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is linked to a larger network connection issue, which you now can see clearly with VSCode 1.79 (May 2023). It includes:

> ### [Network quality indication / Offline detection (web only)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_network-quality-indication)
>
> If you are using a web browser to connect to a remote and you suddenly lose internet connection, the remote indicator updates to reflect that.
>
> Web offline detection displaying "Network appears to be offline" message from the Status bar
>
> [image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_79/offline-indication.gif]